# Why doesn’t Map<String, Set<String>> match Map<T, Set<?>>?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a method with the following signature:

```
public <T> int numberOfValues(Map<T, Set<?>> map)
```

However I can’t call it passing in a `Map<String, Set<String>>`. For instance, the following doesn’t compile:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
numberOfValues(map);
```

The error message being that:

```
numberOfValues (java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Set<?>>) in class cannot be applied to (java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>)
```

However, if I change to the following all is fine:

```
public <T, V> int numberOfValues(Map<T, Set<V>> map)
```

However I’m not at all interested in `V`, as I just want to know the size of each of the sets.

For completeness sake, this is the whole method:

```
public <T, V> int numberOfValues(Map<T, Set<V>> map) {
    int n = 0;
    for (T key : map.keySet()) {
        n += map.get(key).size();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Which I’m aware it can also be accomplished like this, but isn’t the point of the question :)

```
public <T> int numberOfValues(Map<?, Set<T>> map) {
    int n = 0;
    for (Set<T> value : map.values()) {
        n += value.size();
    }
    return n;
}
```

**Update:** yet another way of achieving the same

```
public <T> int numberOfValues(Map<?, Set<T>> map) {
    int n = 0;
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        n += map.get(key).size();
    }

    return n;
}
```

**Final update:**
Thanks to Jorn’s answer, this is the final implementation...

```
public int numberOfValues(Map<?, ? extends Set<?>> map) {
    int n = 0;
    for (Set<?> value : map.values()) {
        n += value.size();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you're trying to call the method, which makes it hard to help you. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Fixed, I added a code snippet of how the method is called with an empty map.

Comment: And can't `map.get(key)` return `null`?

Comment: See this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149591/why-is-this-conversion-not-valid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the fact that `Set<?>` is also used as a generic parameter. And generics are *invariant*. i.e. when the parameter is `Map<String, Set<?>>`, the passed argument must be exactly `Map<String, Set<?>` (or a subtype of). Whereas with `Set<V>` the type argument is inferred.

You can solve this by using a bounded wildcard:

```
public <T> int numberOfValues(Map<T, ? extends Set<?>> map) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I edited the question and added an implementation with no types at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In your `numberOfValues` method, it is completely legal to write something like

```
Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(1);
set.add("Powned");
map.put(null, set);
```

You can replace the `null` with a suitable key already in the map to make a valid mapping, utterly breaking the type safety in the surrounding code.

Either infer or explicitly define the type of the set, or add a wildcard bound preventing mutating map access (like `? extends Set<?>`)